# Alamofire async call

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have a simple problem. I'm connecting to my RESTful server and trying to connect. I do get a response and everything works perfect, however when I try to call a function to set a variable, it just doesn't call it.

**Code:**

```
//
//  LoginClass.swift
//  LoginApp
//
//  Created by Tarek Adel on 12/3/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Tarek Adel. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Alamofire;
import UIKit;

class LoginClass {
    var result: Bool = false;

    var username: String
    var password: String

    init(username: String, password:String) {
        self.username = username;
        self.password = password;
    }


    func login() -> Void {
        let data = [
            "grant_type" : "password",
            "username" : self.username,
            "password" : self.password,
            "client_secret":"xxxxxx",
            "client_id":"xxxxxx",
            "scope": ""
        ]
        Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8000/oauth/token", method: .post, parameters: data)
            .responseJSON { response in

                //to get status code
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 200:
                        self.loginSuccess();
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
                //to get JSON return value

                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    print(JSON)
                }

        }
    }

    func loginSuccess() {
        self.result = true;
    }

}
```

This is where I check the `self.result` :

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let username = usernameTextField.text!;
    let password = passwordTextField.text!;

    let loginClass = LoginClass(username: username, password:password)
    loginClass.login()

    if(loginClass.result == true) {
        resultLabel.text = "Correct!"
    } else {
        resultLabel.text = "Wrong Credentials"
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you thinking that it is not executing that function, have you put breakpoint inside that function and trying to debug it?

Comment: Agreed with Nirav. I'm assuming you're having trouble calling `self.loginSuccess` inside of the switch statement. Are you sure that `status` is getting set in the optional binding above?

Comment: yes, I have checked that it calls the self.loginSuccess but the self.result never changes

Comment: Where are you checking `self.loginSuccess`?

Comment: Can you show us your code where you check for the value of `self.result`?

Comment: I added it to the main question.

Comment: @TarekAdel You are always getting false because `login` method is making an async call so that `self.result = true` is executing later when you get your response and that if condition of your execute before of that.

Comment: I think that may be the case, but do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use completion handler with your `login` method because it is making an Async call, so make one `completionHandler` with your login method and than execute that if condition inside that `completionHandler`.

```
func login(completionHandler: (_ result: Bool) -> ()) {
    let data = [
        "grant_type" : "password",
        "username" : self.username,
        "password" : self.password,
        "client_secret":"xxxxxx",
        "client_id":"xxxxxx",
        "scope": ""
    ]
    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8000/oauth/token", method: .post, parameters: data)
        .responseJSON { response in

            //to get status code
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 200:
                    //to get JSON return value
                    if let result = response.result.value {
                        let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                        print(JSON)
                    }
                    completionHandler(true)
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
            }                
    }
}
```

Now call this login method like this.

```
self.login { (result) in
    if(result)
    {
        resultLabel.text = "Correct!"
    }
    else{
        resultLabel.text = "Wrong Credentials"
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you want JSON response also then make completion handler with two parameter Bool and Dictionary and pass JSON also with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped

Comment: @TarekAdel Welcome mate :)